# Set ruler does nothing

Tags: ruler

I would like to use the setruler option in order to know which line number and column my cursor is on. I have tried typing the command manually by typing `:set ruler` and also adding `set ruler` to my `~/.vimrc` but neither seem to have any effect. Any ideas why this is? My VIM version is:

```
$ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)
Included patches: 1-2269
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
-arabic            -file_in_path      -mouse_urxvt       -termguicolors
+autocmd           -find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -terminal
-autochdir         -float             +multi_byte        +terminfo
-autoservername    -folding           -multi_lang        +termresponse
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          -textobjects
-balloon_eval_term +fork()            -netbeans_intg     -textprop
-browse            -gettext           -num64             -timers
+builtin_terms     -hangul_input      -packages          -title
-byte_offset       +iconv             -path_extra        -toolbar
-channel           +insert_expand     -perl              +user_commands
-cindent           -job               -persistent_undo   -vartabs
-clientserver      +jumplist          -printer           +vertsplit
-clipboard         -keymap            -profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_compl     -lambda            -python            +visual
+cmdline_hist      -langmap           -python3           +visualextra
-cmdline_info      -libcall           -quickfix          -viminfo
+comments          -linebreak         -reltime           +vreplace
-conceal           -lispindent        -rightleft         +wildignore
-cryptv            +listcmds          -ruby              -wildmenu
-cscope            +localmap          +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorbind        -lua               -signs             +writebackup
-cursorshape       -menu              -smartindent       -X11
-dialog            -mksession         -sound             +xfontset
-diff              +modify_fname      -spell             -xim
-digraphs          +mouse             -startuptime       -xpm
-dnd               -mouseshape        -statusline        -xsmp
-ebcdic            -mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
-emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         -syntax            -xterm_save
-eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        
+ex_extra          -mouse_netterm     -tag_old_static    
-extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white     
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-iU6mZD/vim-8.1.2269=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DTINY_VIMRC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -ldl
```

The expected behaviour is that the line and column number appears in the status bar as shown here:

https://linuxhint.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/11-12.png

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Do you also set `statusline`? I believe that the `ruler` setting doesn't do anything if you have a custom `statusline` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ruler is not available when compiled without `+cmdline_info` feature.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27ruler%27)
View local documentation about Vim commands and options with `:h`. Here `:h ruler` would have given you that information.

In Debian and Ubuntu, you can install a more featureful Vim with `vim-athena` or `vim-nox` packages. Those will come with `+cmdline-info`.

Comment: Thanks. That documentation was helpful.